# Reload the page after tabbar change

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, master-detail

I am using a masterdetail app inside a tab bar controller. From one tab, i am collecting some data and using

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
```

This goes to the first tab which has the masterview controller. However, i have updated the database in my third tab and the table contents have to be updated in the master detail app of first tab. Effectively i need to call the

```
viewDidLoad
```

of the master detail app after setting the selected index. Could anyone say how to do this.

Comment: Is the table of contents in a UITableview object?

Answer (score 3):

rewrite the contents of `viewDidLoad` in a new method, and call them on `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, using viewWillAppear, i was able to get back the control, but how can i update the table contents which is picking from the updated database?

Comment: heard of `reloadData` method for tableview?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

- Change your code in the 1st tab to update when your view appears instead of loads (recommended method)
- Call the view method of the controller to force the viewDidLoad if you have a reference to the controller.

  ```
  [self.localFundraiserController view];
  ```
- Use notifications. In your 3rd tab after the user has entered some data, send a notification. In your first tab, look for notifications and respond.

  ```
  //1st tab controller:
  -(void)viewDidLoad {
       [self loadUserData:nil]
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadUserData:) name:@"kUserEnteredData" object:nil];
  }

  -(void)loadUserData:(NSNotification*)notification {
      id userData = notification.object;
  }

  //3rd tab controller when user entered data
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kUserEnteredData" object:userData];
  ```

When posting the notification, you can pass object data which would be read in your loadUserData method. This is optional. The problem with notifications is that there is no guarantee that the view in your first tab is still loaded, so it may not be able to respond to the notification.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, using viewWillAppear, i was able to get back the control, but how can i update the table contents which is picking from the updated database? Using your this, i can get some notification, but can i update the table contents/

Comment: if it is a tableViewController, then use [self.tableView reloadData]; If it is a viewController with a tableView on it, then you need to make a reference to the tableView and reloadData in a similar fashion.